# Seaborn: Plot multi color points without breaking lines in point plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset like this. Is there a possibility to plot the dots, with lines not breaking when the color changes? the color of the line, joining green to red, or red to green can be either green or red (it doesn't matter).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

index = np.arange(1, 49, 1)
value = np.append(np.arange(1,25,1), np.arange(25,1,-1))
color_choice = np.random.choice(['YES', 'NO'], 48, p=[0.3, 0.7])

dt = pd.DataFrame(zip(index, value, color_choice), columns=['index', 'value', 'color_choice'])

plt.figure(figsize = (16, 5))
color_dict = dict({'NO':'green', 'YES':'red'})
sns.pointplot(x="index", y="value", data=dt, hue="color_choice", palette=color_dict);
```

[image]

What I am looking for is there should be a continuous plot, where the dots are joined and based on condition in column `color_choice` , the dots are either green or red. The line between them can be of any color

Comment: Now there is a green line between `no-no` and a red line between `yes-yes`. What exactly do you want to draw between `no-yes` and between `yes-no`?

Comment: both, between no-yes, and yes-no, basically whenever the color switches, the line should continue and not break

Comment: when it goes from green to red, and red to green, the line continuity breaks

Comment: Yes, of course it breaks.  What color do you want there? It is nor `yes` nor `no` there. As Seaborn doesn't know either, it chooses to leave those parts blank.

Comment: any idea, other than seaborn, how can I get continuous line with color codes at different points

Comment: @HardikGupta : Try to read JohanC's questions twice, again. He is basically asking you if you go from a green point to a red point, then the line which was green until the green point, which color should it have when connecting to the upcoming red point in front of it. Avoid redundant discussion and clearly explain in your question what you want. Best would be to include a sample figure (even handmade figure will work) in your question. Otherwise, this discussion is leading no where.  Look at the answer below. It just uses a single color line. Just because of the poor explanation in question

Comment: @Sheldore - I have edited my question, I hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a less elegant way, using `matplotlib` in place of `seaborn`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set()

index = np.arange(1, 49, 1)
value = np.append(np.arange(1,25,1), np.arange(25,1,-1))
color_choice = np.random.choice(['YES', 'NO'], 48, p=[0.3, 0.7])

dt = pd.DataFrame(zip(index, value, color_choice), columns=['index', 'value', 'color_choice'])

plt.figure(figsize = (16, 5))
color_dict = dict({'NO':'green', 'YES':'red'})

plt.plot(dt["index"], dt["value"], color="green", lw=3)
plt.plot(dt[dt["color_choice"] == "NO"]["index"], dt[dt["color_choice"] == "NO"]["value"], "o", color = "green", markersize = 10)
plt.plot(dt[dt["color_choice"] == "YES"]["index"], dt[dt["color_choice"] == "YES"]["value"], "o", color = "red", markersize = 10)

plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]